Estoy intentando conectar Vue.js con Django, y webpack me está dando un ValidationError
Estoy realizando una pequeña investigación para un proyecto y mi primer paso es hacer un entorno con Django y Vue.js para poder manejar todo el frontend en una forma organizada.
Estoy siguiendo el siguiente tutorial: https://www.codigojs.com/blog/integrar-django-3-con-vue-3/
Todo va bien hasta que llego a la sección donde debo incluir {% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %} en el index.html. Cuando levanto la página, me lanza el siguiente error:
OSError at /
Error reading C:\directorio\del\proyecto\djvue\ui/webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?.

Pensé que podía ser un error asociado a que no había levantado la página en la segunda terminal como indica el tutorial, y en eso me encontré con el siguiente problema: Al correr npm run serve me lanzó este tremendo error:
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'watchOptions'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, prare?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
    at validate (C:\directorio\del\proyecto\djvue\ui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:158:11)
    at new Server (C:\directorio\del\proyecto\djvue\ui\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:270:5)
    at serve (C:directorio\del\proyecto\djvue\ui\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:194:20)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Estuve buscando online sobre el error y me encontré con personas que habían hecho configuraciones aparte de lo que yo hice, y las soluciones no las comprendí realmente ya que estaban asociadas a situaciones diferentes.
Apreciaría muchísimo un poco de ayuda ya que llevo dos sesiones de estudio pegado en el mismo problema y está empezando a sobrepasarme un poco más que nada porque no comprendo cuál es el problema en primer lugar.

Hola, puedes revisar si las versiones que estás usando coinciden con las del curso o guía que estás siguiendo?

Tal vez el servidor de webpack no está corriendo o los recursos no están generados, tal vez te hace falta estos comandos en tu package.json "build": "webpack --mode production" "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"

Hola, lamento la tardanza. Estaba revisando lo que me indicaste del package.json pero no parece cambiar la situación en absoluto. Intenté además correr los comandos build y start y me arroja un error que indica lo siguiente:
ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Directorio\djvue\ui'
Por otro lado, las versiones pueden ser distintas porque la única que instalé detallando la versión fue la que indica el mismo tutorial. Crees que pueda ser eso? más que nada me llama la atención que el error anteriormente indica lo de "watchOptions"

Revisé sobre ese error en línea y lo vi en personas que habían modificado algunos archivos.
Adicionalmente, un amigo me recomendó rehacer el proyecto asegurándome de usar las mismas versiones que detalla el tutorial. Puede ser que eso solucione el problema?

En realidad tienes 2 opciones: hacer el backend separado del frontend o, integrar el front en el back como quieres hacer tu. Yo creo que lo más fácil sería lo primero y conectar al backend mediante una api

Comprendo. Básicamente lo que estaba haciendo hasta ahora es seguir un tutorial para hacer la conexión entre las dos cosas; y entonces ponerme a trabajar. Tengo una idea de cómo quiero diseñar las vistas y estuve mirando cosas más estéticas para la aplicación. Estoy pensando en, claro, buscar una forma un poco más sencilla de solucionar mi problema; pero me gustaría también ver qué tan lejos puedo llegar antes de cambiar la metodología. Además que nunca he integrado front y back así que me parece interesante aprenderlo; por eso sigo pegado en esto
